# Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated prolog

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

Trying to write a program that solves this problem:

"You are given two jugs, a 5-gallon one and a 3-gallon one. Neither of them 
has any measuring markers on it. There is a tap that can be used to fill the 
jugs with water. The goal is to obtain exactly 4 gallons of water."
This is the code I currently have:

```
%(WaterInThree, WaterInFive)
s(A,B).

initial(s(0,0)).

goal(s(A,B)):- A + B =:= 4.

valid(A,B) :- A =< 3, A >=0, B =< 5, B >= 0.

changeState(s(0,B),s(3,B)).
changeState(s(A,0),s(A,5)).
changeState(s(A,B),s(A,0)) :- B > 0, valid(A,B).
changeState(s(A,B),s(0,B)) :- A > 0, valid(A,B).
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- B =< 2, D is A + B, C is B - A, valid(C,D).
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- B > 2, D is B + ( (5 - A) mod 5), valid(C,D).
changeState(s(A,B),s(3,D)) :- B =< 3, D is B - (3 - A), valid(A,D).
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- B =:= 5, C is A + B, D is A - B, valid(C,D).


traverse(StartNode,Sol,_) :- goal(StartNode), Sol = [StartNode].
traverse(StartNode,Sol,Visit) :- changeState(StartNode, NextNode),
   not(member(NextNode, Visit)),
   traverse(NextNode, PartialSol, [NextNode|Visit]),
   Sol = [StartNode | PartialSol].
```

When I execute this code, I get these errors:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] _11226=<3
ERROR:   [12] valid(_11252,5+(5-3)) 
ERROR:   [11] changeState(s(3,5),s(_11302,5+ ...)) 
ERROR:   [10] traverse(s(3,5),_11336,[s(3,5),...|...]) 
ERROR:    [9] traverse(s(3,0),_11388,[s(3,0),...]) 
ERROR:    [8] traverse(s(0,0),_11440,[s(0,0)]) 
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Not really sure what the issue is, I've been trying to fix this for hours on end and can't figure out what's wrong. Can't even properly test if the changeState predicates I've created even work because of this so it's extremely frustrating. Would appreciate any help!

**EDIT** I've narrowed it down to the this line causing the error:

```
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- B > 2, D is B + ( (5 - A) mod 5), valid(C,D).
```

Can't really see how this would cause that error though.

Comment: Do you know what `=` means in Prolog. See: [Predicate =/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2)

Comment: Still I ask the same question: `Do you know what = means in Prolog?`

Comment: Yes I know what = means in prolog

Comment: If you know what `=` means in Prolog then why did you change [it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53794232/revisions)?

Comment: What was the query that caused the error?

Comment: Like I mentioned before, the = was incorrect originally and I changed it, this was just an older version, and I didn't bother editing at first since it didn't affect the outcome, but since I edited with the exact line that's causing the error I figured I'd update. The query I run that causes the error is: ?- traverse(s(0,0), Sol, [s(0,0)]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't really see how this

```
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- B > 2, D is B + ( (5 - A) mod 5), valid(C,D).
```

> would cause that error though.

```
_10148=<3
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

---

For

```
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- 
  B > 2, 
  D is B + ( (5 - A) mod 5), 
  valid(C,D).
```

when this is executed (called) the query is

```
changeState(s(0, 5), X)

A is bound to 0
B is bound to 5
X is bound to s(C,D)
```

then for

```
B > 2
```

the query is

```
5 > 2
```

which is true

then for

```
D is B + ( (5 - A) mod 5)
```

the query is

```
D is 5 + ( (5 - 0) mod 5)

D is bound to 5
```

then for

```
valid(C,D)

C is unbound
D is bound to 5
```

the query is

```
valid (<unbound>,5)
```

the only predicate to match is

```
valid(A,B) :- A =< 3, A >=0, B =< 5, B >= 0.

A is unbound
B is bound to 5
```

then for

```
A =< 3
```

since A is unbound the comparison `=<` gives the error because it needs both variables to be bound.

So back at this statement

```
changeState(s(A,B),s(C,D)) :- B > 2, D is B + ( (5 - A) mod 5), valid(C,D).
```

you need to bind `C` to a value.

---

If you use set up the trace with

```
?- visible(+all),leash(-all).
```

then enable tracing

```
?- trace.
```

and run your query you get

```
?- traverse(s(0,0), Sol, [s(0,0)]).
   Call: (8) traverse(s(0, 0), _9866, [s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (8) traverse(s(0, 0), _9866, [s(0, 0)])
   Call: (9) goal(s(0, 0))
   Unify: (9) goal(s(0, 0))
   Call: (10) 0+0=:=4
   Fail: (10) 0+0=:=4
   Fail: (9) goal(s(0, 0))   
   Redo: (8) traverse(s(0, 0), _9866, [s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (8) traverse(s(0, 0), _9866, [s(0, 0)])
   Call: (9) changeState(s(0, 0), _10092)
   Unify: (9) changeState(s(0, 0), s(3, 0))
   Exit: (9) changeState(s(0, 0), s(3, 0))
^  Call: (9) not(member(s(3, 0), [s(0, 0)]))
^  Unify: (9) not(user:member(s(3, 0), [s(0, 0)]))
^  Exit: (9) not(user:member(s(3, 0), [s(0, 0)]))
   Call: (9) traverse(s(3, 0), _10116, [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (9) traverse(s(3, 0), _10116, [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Call: (10) goal(s(3, 0))
   Unify: (10) goal(s(3, 0))
   Call: (11) 3+0=:=4
   Fail: (11) 3+0=:=4
   Fail: (10) goal(s(3, 0))   
   Redo: (9) traverse(s(3, 0), _10116, [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (9) traverse(s(3, 0), _10116, [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Call: (10) changeState(s(3, 0), _10116)
   Unify: (10) changeState(s(3, 0), s(3, 5))
   Exit: (10) changeState(s(3, 0), s(3, 5))   
^  Call: (10) not(member(s(3, 5), [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Unify: (10) not(user:member(s(3, 5), [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Exit: (10) not(user:member(s(3, 5), [s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
   Call: (10) traverse(s(3, 5), _10140, [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (10) traverse(s(3, 5), _10140, [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Call: (11) goal(s(3, 5))
   Unify: (11) goal(s(3, 5))
   Call: (12) 3+5=:=4
   Fail: (12) 3+5=:=4
   Fail: (11) goal(s(3, 5))   
   Redo: (10) traverse(s(3, 5), _10140, [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (10) traverse(s(3, 5), _10140, [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Call: (11) changeState(s(3, 5), _10140)
   Unify: (11) changeState(s(3, 5), s(3, 0))
   Call: (12) 5>0
   Exit: (12) 5>0
   Call: (12) valid(3, 5)
   Unify: (12) valid(3, 5)
   Call: (13) 3=<3
   Exit: (13) 3=<3
   Call: (13) 3>=0
   Exit: (13) 3>=0
   Call: (13) 5=<5
   Exit: (13) 5=<5
   Call: (13) 5>=0
   Exit: (13) 5>=0
   Exit: (12) valid(3, 5)   
   Exit: (11) changeState(s(3, 5), s(3, 0))
^  Call: (11) not(member(s(3, 0), [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Unify: (11) not(user:member(s(3, 0), [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Fail: (11) not(user:member(s(3, 0), [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
   Redo: (11) changeState(s(3, 5), _10140)
   Unify: (11) changeState(s(3, 5), s(0, 5))
   Call: (12) 3>0
   Exit: (12) 3>0
   Call: (12) valid(3, 5)
   Unify: (12) valid(3, 5)
   Call: (13) 3=<3
   Exit: (13) 3=<3
   Call: (13) 3>=0
   Exit: (13) 3>=0
   Call: (13) 5=<5
   Exit: (13) 5=<5
   Call: (13) 5>=0
   Exit: (13) 5>=0
   Exit: (12) valid(3, 5)
   Exit: (11) changeState(s(3, 5), s(0, 5))
^  Call: (11) not(member(s(0, 5), [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Unify: (11) not(user:member(s(0, 5), [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Exit: (11) not(user:member(s(0, 5), [s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
   Call: (11) traverse(s(0, 5), _10164, [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (11) traverse(s(0, 5), _10164, [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Call: (12) goal(s(0, 5))
   Unify: (12) goal(s(0, 5))
   Call: (13) 0+5=:=4
   Fail: (13) 0+5=:=4
   Fail: (12) goal(s(0, 5))   
   Redo: (11) traverse(s(0, 5), _10164, [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Unify: (11) traverse(s(0, 5), _10164, [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)])
   Call: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), _10164)
   Unify: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(3, 5))
   Exit: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(3, 5))
^  Call: (12) not(member(s(3, 5), [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Unify: (12) not(user:member(s(3, 5), [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Fail: (12) not(user:member(s(3, 5), [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
   Redo: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), _10164)
   Unify: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(0, 0))
   Call: (13) 5>0
   Exit: (13) 5>0
   Call: (13) valid(0, 5)
   Unify: (13) valid(0, 5)
   Call: (14) 0=<3
   Exit: (14) 0=<3
   Call: (14) 0>=0
   Exit: (14) 0>=0
   Call: (14) 5=<5
   Exit: (14) 5=<5
   Call: (14) 5>=0
   Exit: (14) 5>=0
   Exit: (13) valid(0, 5)
   Exit: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(0, 0))
^  Call: (12) not(member(s(0, 0), [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Unify: (12) not(user:member(s(0, 0), [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
^  Fail: (12) not(user:member(s(0, 0), [s(0, 5), s(3, 5), s(3, 0), s(0, 0)]))
   Redo: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), _10164)
   Unify: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(0, 5))
   Call: (13) 0>0
   Fail: (13) 0>0
   Redo: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), _10164)
   Unify: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(_10148, _10150))
   Call: (13) 5=<2
   Fail: (13) 5=<2
   Redo: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), _10164)
   Unify: (12) changeState(s(0, 5), s(_10148, _10150))
   Call: (13) 5>2
   Exit: (13) 5>2
   Call: (13) _10150 is 5+(5-0)mod 5
   Exit: (13) 5 is 5+(5-0)mod 5
   Call: (13) valid(_10148, 5)
   Unify: (13) valid(_10148, 5)
   Call: (14) _10148=<3
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [14] _11032=<3
ERROR:   [13] valid(_11058,5) at *.pl:10
ERROR:   [12] changeState(s(0,5),s(_11096,5)) at *.pl:17
ERROR:   [11] traverse(s(0,5),_11124,[s(0,5),...|...]) at *.pl:26
ERROR:   [10] traverse(s(3,5),_11176,[s(3,5),...|...]) at *.pl:28
ERROR:    [9] traverse(s(3,0),_11228,[s(3,0),...]) at *.pl:28
ERROR:    [8] traverse(s(0,0),_11280,[s(0,0)]) at *.pl:28
ERROR:    [7] <user>
   Exception: (14) _10148=<3 ? Unknown option (h for help)
```